# jquery each() iteraton

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, each

I want to multiply the input value with p tag when press the button. My html structure is like this:

```
<div class="table">
    <input class="input" type="text" /> 
    <p>10</p>
</div>

<div class="table">
    <input class="input" type="text" />
    <p>20</p>
</div>

<div class="bill"></div> // the result must be displayed in this tag
<button class="button">Calculate</button>
```

I use each method to select input elements and it is my jquery structure:

```
$(function() {
   function calculate()
   {
      $('input.input').each(function(index) {
      var inputValue = $(this).val();
      var valueP = $(this).next('p').text();
      var result = inputValue * valueP;
      $('.bill').text(result);// displays only last multipled result
      console.log(result); // displays all multipled results
   });
   }

   $('.button').click(function() {
       calculate();
   });
});
```

I achive to multiply input value with p tag but the problem is that only last multiplied input value displays in the class with "bill". But it looks fine with console.log
Also, it is fine with "document.write(result)". How can I fix this problem?
By the way, someone could say me please how can I sum all multiplied results!
Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MG4JZ/12/)

```
function calculate() {
    var result = 0;
    $('input.input').each(function(index) {
        var inputValue = Number($(this).val());
        var valueP = Number($(this).next('p').text());
        result += inputValue * valueP;
//as you were adding here it will each time update the .bill
        console.log(result);
    });
    $('.bill').text(result);
}

$('.button').click(calculate);​
```

**update**

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MG4JZ/13/)** for showing all calculated result beside adding them

```
function calculate()
{
   //var result = 0;
  $('input.input').each(function(index) {
  var inputValue = Number($(this).val());
  var valueP = Number($(this).next('p').text());
  var  result = inputValue * valueP;
  $('.bill').append(result+"<br/>");
  console.log(result);
});
}

$('.button').click(calculate);​
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindly response. It is good way to add all multiplied results but the main problem for me is that I want to show all multiplied results beside of adding them!

Comment: for that you can use `$('.bill').append(result);` in side the `.each` loop

Comment: it works great! thank you! why can't I remember "append" method. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
function calculate() {
    var result = 0;
    $('input.input').each(function(index) {
        var inputValue = Number($(this).val());
        var valueP = Number($(this).next('p').text());
        result += inputValue * valueP;
        $('.bill').append(result);
        console.log(result);
    });

}

$('.button').click(calculate);​
```